# Cannot open svc file with wcfTestClient.exe

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I just added wcf service to my website. 
web.config look like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="Realstuf.Service">

    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress = "http://ismyrealstuff/Services/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>

    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <endpoint address ="http://ismyrealstuff/Services/Service.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Realstuf.IService" behaviorConfiguration="FirstServiceBehaviour"/>

    <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="FirstServiceBehaviour">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

A svc file is added and service.cs and Iservice.cs files are added in app_code directory. No Assemblyinfo.cs file is found.

When I tried to open svc file in wcftestclient "Failed to add service" error has generated.
The Error detail says:

> Error: Cannot read D:\Projects\IsMyRealStuf\IsMyRealStuffWeb\Services\Service.svc.    Cannot load file D:\Projects\IsMyRealStuf\IsMyRealStuffWeb\Services\Service.svc as an Assembly. Check the FusionLogs for more Information.    Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\Projects\IsMyRealStuf\IsMyRealStuffWeb\Services\Service.svc' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

If I add any assemblyinfo.cs file is it solution for this? then How ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `http://ismyrealstuff/Services/Service.svc` as service, not the file on your disk.